# Given $A:R^4 \rightarrow R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A:R^4 \rightarrow R^4$.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4a+12 & -2 & -4a-11 &-12a-29 \\ 
 4a+10& 0 &-4a-11  & -12a-29\\ 
 a&4 & -a-5 &-3a-11 \\ 
 a+4& -2 &-a-2  & -3a-6
\end{pmatrix}$

For what values of variable $a$ the non-zero vector $x$ such that $x\in Ker(A)$ and $x\in Im(A)$ does'nt  exist?

---

I came to conclusion that equality $Ker(A^2) = Ker(A)$ must hold. It's too difficult to find both parts. Probably exists more convinient method? To find ranks of $A^2$ and $A$, for example, and compare.
If $a \neq -2 $  $rank(A)=3$ and $rank(A)=2$ oterwise. But how to evaluate the rank of $A^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to help, but I dont understand the question. Do you want a vector $x \in Ker(A) \wedge x \notin Im(A) $? Or a vector that doesnt belong $Ker $ nor $Im$?

Comment: Uhm, if that is the case, the rank - nulity thm answers the question with a really strong answer: There is no such $a$.

Comment: I think the question is, for which values $a$ does there not exist $x \neq 0$ s.t. $x\in Ker(A)$ and $x\in Im(A)$.

Comment: Yesss!!!!!!!!!!